# MS BI Warehouse project

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, ssis, ssas

Is there any link or zip file where I could get whole MS BI warehouse project (sample) from starting to end? (2008)

Incremental load and even possible creating cubes too. What kind of problems one faced in real time projects, such things.

I could find things on you tube in parts but couldn't link it. Please help.

Rohan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best reference implementation for the MS BI stack is Project REAL. According to Microsoft:

> In Project REAL we are creating a reference implementation of a
>   business intelligence (BI) system using real large-scale data from a
>   real customer. The goal is to discover the best practices for creating
>   BI systems with SQL Server 2005 and to build a system that exhibits as
>   many of those best practices as we can. This project is not just a
>   demo —we are creating this system for ongoing operation. It is a
>   complete system, including daily incremental updates of the data,
>   large multiuser workloads, and system monitoring.

It contains:

1. A set of instructions for setting up the environment
2. Guidance on how to explore the implementation
3. A sample relational data warehouse database (a subset of the Project REAL data warehouse)
4. A sample source database (from which we pull incremental updates)
5. SSIS packages that implement the ETL operations
6. An SSAS cube definition and scripts for processing the cube from the sample warehouse
7. Sample SSRS reports
8. Sample data mining models for predicting out-of-stock
   conditions in stores
9. Sample client views in briefing books for the Proclarity and Panorama BI front-end tools

You can download it here - http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=12134

Answer (score 2):

you can get the AdventureWorks database and datawarehouse (with the cube) here: http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/

not sure about the SSIS packages

Comment: Thanks for you reply. i need whole ETL strategy (ssis)step by step and problems we faced in real time and their solutions. I already installed AW db.